# typeError in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

i'm very new in python and i don't understand what the error say and what i do wrong

any help would be appreciated

thanks

my code:

```
class TSP:
    def __init__(self, initial_node, adjacency_matrix):
        self.initial_node = initial_node
        self.adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix

    stack = {"cost": {}, "distances": {}}

    def distance(self, start_node, end_node):
        self.stack["distances"]["dist%s-%s" %(start_node, end_node)] = self.adjacency-matrix[start_node][end_node]

    def cost(self, visit_nodes, end_node_cost):
        if len(visit_nodes) == 2:
            node_set = visit_nodes.remove(end_node_cost)
            self.distance(node_set[0], end_node_cost)
        print (self.stack)


test = TSP(1, [[0, 10, 15, 20], [10, 0, 35, 25], [15, 35, 0, 30], [20, 25, 30, 0]])

print (test.cost([1, 2], 2))
```

and my error is :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study the backtrace to discover where the error is coming from. 
 `visit_nodes.remove()` returns `None` (see [the official docs for the `list.remove` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)—no return value is mentioned). Therefore `node_set` is `None`. Therefore `node_set[0]` in the subsequent line fails.  You presumably mean to dereference the list itself, i.e. `visit_nodes[0]`.

Comment: This won't be the last of your problems however. (1) You'll presumably be able to fix the `KeyError` resulting from using `"distance"` where you mean `"distances"`. (2) You'll also have to program around the fact that the `"distances"` sub-dictionary is empty when you appear to want to use it.  (3) You may not notice, until much much later in your development,  the insidious effect of calling `.remove()` on a `list` that gets passed into the `cost()` method, which has the (possibly undesirable) effect of modifying the original object that was passed.

Comment: ok i corrected your sugestions and i still get that typeError